# can we use more than one cassandra CQL collections ( set,list,map )in a single query?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

```
create table seller(
    seller_id int primary key,
    seller_name text,
    seller_email set<text>, 
    seller_address map<text>, 
    seller_phone list<text>,
    product_id int,
    product_title_text,
    product_description text,
    product_trackno int,
    product_bidoption text,
    bid_startdate date,
    bid_closedate date,
    bid_startprice int,
    bid_withdrawdate date);

    SyntaxException: line 1:110 mismatched input '>' expecting ',' (...<text>,
        seller_address map<text[>],...)
```

What changes should be made in order to execute?

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can, with some adjustments:

1) It helps if the type of a column isn't linked to the column name by an underscore.  Instead of:

```
product_title_text,
```

This will work:

```
product_title text,
```

2) You'll also need to provide both types for the map collection.  Instead of:

```
seller_address map<TEXT>,
```

This will work:

```
seller_address map<TEXT,TEXT>,
```

Full CQL:

```
create table seller(
  seller_id int primary key,
  seller_name text,
  seller_email set<TEXT>,
  seller_address map<TEXT,TEXT>, 
  seller_phone list<TEXT>, 
  product_id int,
  product_title text,
  product_description text,
  product_trackno int,
  product_bidoption text,
  bid_startdate date,
  bid_closedate date,
  bid_startprice int,
  bid_withdrawdate date);
```

Also, are you really only ever going to query this table by `seller_id`?  If not, you may want to rethink the primary key definition.